# Publishing html directly from ftp to wordpress

Tags: customization, html, ftp

I have a program for a booking programme and within that is an "Update Website" button which originally would ftp the html created straight in place of the old one meaning once you click update website it will post the most up to date information without having to publish. Only recently changed to wordpress and ma trying to achieve the same thing. I can successfully post into FTP and all, the only issue occurs as I am unsure how to make the link from one page send through to the ftp folder with the html file and therefore view this information without having to login to wordpress and publish it.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: WordPress pages  are php powered. If you only need to show HTML files why choose WordPress?

Comment: Its not only showing html. Its only one page out of all of them. If there is a better way to incorporate publishing from an external source then i would do that but thats the only way i can think of atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the software publishes everything to a directory, maybe something like:

```
booking/index.html
booking/otherstuff.jpg
```

...then you can just link to it from your WordPress part like you would normally:

```
http://www.example.com/booking/
```

...when someone clicks the link, they see the booking section. WordPress is none the wiser, and will happily carry on powering everything else.